# Can't import tween using import

Tags: babeljs, webpack-4, tween.js

I have an es6 script that include a tween library with es6 import. The code works fine if it's not transpiled, I mean I can import tween and use it inside the script, if I use webpacke with my configuration the script exit with an error becouse the TWEEN is somehow undefined.

I have tried change extension of tween file with mjs but it generate other errors like 
`require is not defined` 
I webpack add core-js modules using require funcition

```
require("core-js/modules/es.symbol");
```

The code with issue

```
'use strict';

...
import {TWEEN} from '../threejs/tween.js';
//import {TWEEN} from '../threejs/tween.js';
...
export class CustomClass extends ParentClass {

    constructor(arguments) {

        super(arguments);


        this.tweenGroup = new TWEEN.Group(); // the line that generate "Cant get Group of undefined"
    }
...
}

...
```

this is my babel-loader configuration configuration

```
{
      test: /\.m?js$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          sourceType: 'module'
        }
      }
    },
```

my babel configuration is look like this

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            {
                debug: true,
                useBuiltIns: 'usage',
                corejs: 3
            }
        ]
    ],
    plugins: [
        // '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
        // '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
        // '@babel/runtime-corejs2',
        // '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
        // '@babel/plugin-syntax-async-generators',
        // '@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator',
        // '@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator',
        '@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs',
        // '@babel/plugin-transform-typeof-symbol'
    ]
};
```

The code with TWEEN import (the first block of code I posted) work just fine if I use it in a project that is not transpiled with babel, but it generate the error if I run devserver. I don't understand why I can't import the Tween properly afetr compilation.

I will apriciate any help.l

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: I realized I had rather different setup and different issue than you did, but while searching the solution I found [this thread with recommendation for npm intalling tween](https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/issues/412) for babel workflow. Maybe that is helpful for you.

I still leave my initial reply here, could be useful for anyone else: 
I had some trouble including TWEEN within my js project (eg using import * as TWEEN from '...'), but following the [those steps for simple installation](https://github.com/sole/tween.js) I got it working after I included it in HTML, not in js:

```
<script src="js/libs/Tween.js"></script>
```